# Kendo Grid having text box with Autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am developing a Grid which has Text Box as input field.

```
 $("#gvGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dsource,
            columns: [
                        {
                            field: "MURQuestionnaireModel.QuestionText",
                            title: "QuestionText", width: 100
                        }, {
                            //field: "MURExpctedAnswersModel.AnswerText",
                            template: '<input type="text" Name="gvAnswer" id="**gvAnswer**' + '#= **MURQuestionnaireId** #" Value=" #= MURExpctedAnswersModel.AnswerText # "/>',
                            title: "Answer", width: 100
                        }
            ]

        });
```

Here id for the text box is "gvAnswer" and MURQuestionnaireID e.g gvAnswer8, gvAnswer9

I also have code for autocomplete :

```
 $('input[id^="gvAnswer"]').autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: data
        });
    });
```

here for all those control which starts from gvAnswer apply Auto-complete , however auto-complete is not working.

please help/ suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exactly did you initialize these inputs into autoComplete? Do you do this in the [dataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-dataBound) event of the Grid? If you are not, give a try when the dataBound event is triggered